# Merge two lists by id and select the item of with a max value

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists of `Level`, and I want to merge them into a single list with only unique
indexes, and having the higher highscore of the two.

The Level object.

```
public class Level
{

    public int Index { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public int Highscore { get; set; }
    public Level(int index,string user, int highscore)
    {
         Highscore = highscore;
         User = user;
         Index = index;
    }


}
```

I have this test code

```
List<Level> Levels = new List<Level>();
List<Level> otherlevels = new List<Level>();

Levels.Add(new Level(1, "Test", 1));
Levels.Add(new Level(2, "Test", 2));
Levels.Add(new Level(3, "Test", 4));
Levels.Add(new Level(4, "Test", 1));

otherlevels.Add(new Level(1, "Test", 4));
otherlevels.Add(new Level(2, "Test", 4));
otherlevels.Add(new Level(3, "Test", 1));

//some linq code here
```

What I want from the linq code is a list that will have these 4 items.

```
Level(1,"Test",4)
Level(2,"Test",4)
Level(3,"Test",4)
Level(4,"Test",1)
```

I managed to group by Index and select the first, but I dont know how to select the one with the max Highscore.

Comment: use orderby highscore descending and select the first result?

Comment: You are using a constructor of `Level` that is not posted.

Comment: The constructor assigns the values appropriately I didn't feel the need to post it as it would make the post longer and add no information

Comment: @BennyGafanovich Well it would make a huge difference if your constructor was `Level(int index, string user, int highscore)` or `Level(int highscore, string user, int index)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you got 90% of the way there by grouping the levels. Now you just need to order them to grab the largest scoring result:

```
List<Level> newLevels = from x in Enumerable.Concat(Levels, otherLevels)
                        group x by x.Index into grp
                        select grp.OrderByDescending(x => x.HighScore).First()
```

In addition to being more concise than Thomas's solution, this does not have either of his limitations: it will work with lists containing any number of duplicates, and for instances where a level is present in one list but not the other.

Comment: My solution is probably faster, though, since it doesn't need to do any ordering ;). But in the OP's case, your solution is clearly the correct one, so +1.

Answer (score 2):

You can do an outer join:

```
from level in levels
join other in otherLevels on level.Index equals other.Index into tmp
from other in tmp.DefaultIfEmpty()
select other == null
    ? level
    : level.HighScore >= other.HighScore ? level : other;
```

This approach assumes two things:

- each list contains only distinct ids
- each item in `otherLevels` has a corresponding item in `levels` (the reverse doesn't need to be true)

Comment: Oh, but both of these assumptions aren't true.
The lists will contain duplicate Indexes and there is no guarantee that there will be a corresponding index in otherLevels

Comment: @BennyGafanovich, OK, but then, what do you want in the output? Should the output contain duplicate indexes as well?

Comment: @ ThomasLevesque Good point.
It was obvious for me as they are in the same order as they are declared, but I can see how anyone not working with code will get confused.